# Image scaling by height

Tags: css

I'm trying to fit an image inside a div and the div's height is dynamic so I am faced with the problem, that the image overflows the div.

Here is a playground: https://jsfiddle.net/fibin/yzox154p/2/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  padding: 50px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
  some capture
</div>
 <h2>
  some header
 </h2>
 <p>
  some description
 </p>
 <img src="https://filedn.com/ltOdFv1aqz1YIFhf4gTY8D7/ingus-info/BLOGS/Photography-stocks3/stock-photography-slider.jpg"/>
 <span>1/3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `height: 100%` and `object-fit: cover;` for the image?

Comment: that will not work

Comment: You want the div's height to be as large as possible while keeping the aspect ratio, right?

Comment: height of the div must fit to the window height, and image should scale to thats height